# CamelMetricsUpdater not producing metrics as it used to, any change known about?

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, integration, dsl

I'm currently working on an integration project using Camel and we've recently updated to the latest version 2.16.

We had been using the older version (2.14) on a previous project which has been deployed into production and all is working fine.

The [CamelMetricsUpdater](https://gist.github.com/aldrinleal/8262171) was one api that we implemnted and we were able to see various codahale metrics being published from within our application, but at the end we decided not to use it.

Now we actually want to capture some camel metrics in our current project, but haven't been able to see any output being published even after registering our bean in our MetricsServlet and seeing it start up in the console:

```
13:51:17.205 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @2681ms
About to create the Metrics Updater Bean...........
13:51:17.232 [main] INFO  c.c.c.m.p.c.MetricsServletConfiguration - Metrics Updater Bean registered
```

Does anyone know if this still works in 2.16 or more likely have I inadvertently missed something glaringly obvious or incorrectly named my bean?